# What are patterns for having user check correctness of data?

Tags: data, wizard, toggle

In my app design, users need to check the correctness of a list of OCRed data (about 3-10 items depending on the context). Is there a pattern for this? I thought of toggle buttons:

[image: Toggles to mark correct/incorrect items]

Toggles are generally used to turn things on or off though.

A wizard showing each item separately is not desirable, as it would require to many actions from the user to mark all items that generally are correct anyway.

Comment: What do they need to do after each item is marked as correct or incorrect? e.g., if it's incorrect, they might need to make more changes. This would guide your interaction design.

Comment: Users don't correct mistakes; they just indicate wrong data.

Comment: Ok. And how do they know when they are "done" with a page of results?

Comment: Well, I think there will be a button at the button of the list with which users can continue to the next screen. As all items may be correct and users don't have to indicate errors, it's up to the user to know when they are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much of the items do you expect to be wrong? Do you have any data that would suggest that? If majority of items are expected to be correct I would simply list items (correct by default) and have a button "Mark as wrong". It could be an icon alone, this depends on the UI a lot. When the user marks the item as wrong, the background perhaps changes and the content of the button as well. Something like "No wait, it's right".

In the end, a default option (correct) and a single call to action (mark as mistake) would make the whole interaction much clearer that the toggle buttons. Another case against the toggle buttons is, as you already suggested, that it's not a UI pattern commonly used this way.

Comment: I think you make a good point about the expected amount of wrong items. In this particular project I don't have data on that yet. Depending on the relative occurrence of wrong items, I would let users mark correct items or wrong items. Actually marking the correct ones would feel more positive and a check box could in that case be used. As a check mark has the connotation with positivity and thus correctness (see the green circle next to the accepted answer), I would not use it for marking errors though.